# Help with understanding this covariance setup

Tags: probability, bayesian, covariance, prior, regularization

I have been reading a paper that formulates the problem of image registration as a generative model and I have been having a lot of trouble understanding some concepts and I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to shed some light on a particular matter that has me stumped for a few days now.

The problem aims to find a non-linear geometric transformation that aligns the two images geometrically (i.e. find a dense correspondence between the image points). This is an ill-posed problem and needs some regularisation.

So, if the geometric transformation be parameterised by 'w', then we need define some sort of a prior on the distribution of these transformation parameters. In this work, it is done by specifying the prior as a multivariate normal distribution with 0 mean and a covariance matrix as follows:

$$
P(w) = N(w; 0, (\lambda K)^{-1})
$$

where $K$ is the inverse covariance matrix scaled by $\lambda$.

Now, one way to promote plausible transformations in image registration is penalising some measure of the "energy" of the transformation. A commonly used one is something called the bending energy which is a sum of the directional second derivatives and can be written down in a matrix form and the bending energy can be calculated as:

$$
E = w^T M w
$$
where M would be the bending energy matrix.

Now in this work, what the authors have done is taken this bending energy matrix (which has a sparse form) and used that as the inverse covariance matrix i.e.

$$
P(w) = N(w; 0, (\lambda M)^{-1})
$$

Now, I am not sure how this can be used in place of the cover. matrix. From what I see as the definition of the covariance matrix, an entry in the cell (i, j) is given by $E[(w_i-\mu_i)(w_j-\mu_j)]$.

I guess my broad question is how does one translate any such sort of commonly used regularisation schemes like penalising second derivatives of transformations into a valid covariance or inverse covariance matrix. How should one go about specifying this matrix?

Sorry for the long, convoluted question. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have been thinking and reading more about this and I think for an explanation, I need to look at the Gibbs form.

So, the posterior probabilities are as:

$$
P(w|y) \propto P(y|w) P(w)
$$

Now, looking at the Gibbs form, we have:

$$
P(w) \propto \exp^{-E(w)}
$$

where $E(w)$ could encode the bending energy and so maximising the posterior probability should minimise this energy.

And then from the multivariate Gaussian distribution, we have:

$E(w) = (w-w_{0})^{T} K^{-1} (w-w_{0})$

So, as long as we setup the inverse covariance matrix in such a way that the above relationship holds, we are good.

Is that the right way to think about this?

Thanks,

Luca